# Create and Save a File With JavaScript and No Server

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to use the code from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34156339
to make a json object, then save it as a file.  No server, running a local file in my browser.

I might suspect this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28378004
to be the issue, but I can't print anything.

I expected a file saving dialog box.  The results vary between browsers.

In Firefox, Uncaught TypeError: URL.createObjectURL: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 1-argument overloads.

In Chrome, Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.

I am giving it a Blob so there should be no problem.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Please try to make a reproduceable example using something like codesandbox or maybe show us your code so we can better understand what's going on and see if there's any issue

Comment: I used example code from fileSaver.js
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Comment: @StackUser20004 Please add all relevant code inside the question as well. Link can dissapear over time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FileSaver.js](http://purl.eligrey.com/github/FileSaver.js) - it works cross-browser.

Example:

```js
import saveAs from 'FileSaver';

export function saveJSON(object)
{
  const result = JSON.stringify(object, null, 2);
  saveAs(new Blob([result], { type: 'application/json;charset=utf-8;' }), 'result.json', { autoBOM: false });
};
```

Comment: @DarkBee As you wish.

Comment: Doesn't work when it's a local file.  I included fileSaver.js within a script tag to avoid CORS restrictions.  Both the stack trace and console.log confirm it was called.

Comment: If you paste the contents of `FileSaver.js` into your `<script>` tag - then you will be able to step-through its code (available as `window.saveAs`) and see where does it fail.

Comment: It fails exactly where I said it does, createObjectURL

Comment: Just to be precise - you claim that it fails inside `FileSaver.js` - and not inside your code, correct ?